# Spring Boot application with Hibernate runs a different SQL-dialect than specified

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having issues with my Spring Boot application that is running Hibernate and MySQL. When running the code live in my IDE, it works just fine, but when I build the code into a jar-file, it changes the SQL-dialect to H2 database instead of MySQL.

Running in the IDE:

```
17:51:21.326 [main] INFO  SQL dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Running the jar-file:

```
17:24:58.789 [main] INFO  SQL dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Because of that, it won't create some of the tables because some of the columns are using reserved words in H2 that are not reserved in MySQL.

I've tried to force Hibernate to use the MySQL dialect in the application.properties by entering:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

but it won't do anything. I've also added a Hibernate configuration file into main/resources, but it doesn't do anything either. Am I missing something? I use IntelliJ Ultimate as my IDE, MySQL version 8.0.28 and Spring Boot version 3.0.5.

Comment: What build tool do you use ? Maven ? If yes, post the pom.xml. Inspect the application.properties in the jar.  Post the application.properties.

Comment: I use maven:

Here is the application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

Comment: I cant post the whole pom.xml due to charcter limit. But my dependencies are: 
Spring Boot starter web, 
Spring Boot starter data jpa, 
Spring Boot starter validation, 
MySQL connector java, 
Lombok, Spring Boot starter test ,
JUnit